# Reference a ManyToManyField in the __str__ method of a django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In the **str** method of a Django model I am trying to reference a field that is a ManyToManyField.

```
class Level(models.Model):
    code            = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Excercise(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    level           = models.ManyToManyField(Level)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.level.code + ') ' + self.title[:20]
```

The last line of the code

> return self.level.code + ') ' + self.title[:20]

Produces the error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'code'.
I use Python 3.6 and Django 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
class Excercise(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    level           = models.ManyToManyField(Level)

    def __str__(self):
        return '({}) {}'.format(', '.join(self.level.all().values_list('code', flat=True)), self.title[:20])
```

Because, you can access the level objects using `.all()`.

Or if you want to access only the first object, then use like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        elevel = self.level.all().first()
        if elevel:
           return elevel.code + ')' + self.title[:20]
        return self.title[:20]
```

For more information regarding ManyToMany usage, please check the [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).